# ExtJS Integration of Grapesjs

Tags: extjs, grapesjs

We plan to use ExtJS with GrapesJS.

Is it be possible to write a GrapesJS wrapper for ExtJS?

What I am concerned most about is the event handling (ExtJS defines its own implementation).

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is **yes**

I have created a fiddle for you demoing how to integrate third party libraries into Ext JS apps.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cm3

If would like to create a professional and complete GrapesJS Wrapper I would recommend you to check how froala-editor Sencha package  was created as a Sencha CMD package and do your own.

Comment: Good. It 's helpfull with me. Thanks you so much